# ReferenceError: neat is not defined

Tags: gulp

While running gulp sass

```
var gulp = require('gulp');  
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browserSync.reload;

/* Setup scss path */
var paths = {
    scss: './assets/sass/*.scss'
};


/* Sass task */
gulp.task('sass', function () {  
    gulp.src('assets/scss/main.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass({
        includePaths: ['scss'].concat(neat)
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
    /* Reload the browser CSS after every change */
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});
```

I get error " ReferenceError: neat is not defined". Since "neat" is not defined variable. It should be replaced.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

includePaths: ['scss'].concat(neat)

where did you defined neat variable ??

Answer (score 0):

var neat = require('node-neat').includePaths;

and then

includePaths: ['styles'].concat(neat)

Answer (score 0):

maybe

var neat = require('node-neat').includePaths;

and then

includePaths: ['styles'].concat(neat)

??

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('path/to/input.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
      // includePaths: require('node-neat').with('other/path', 'another/path')
      // - or -
      includePaths: require('node-neat').includePaths
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('path/to/output.css'));
});
```

the doc on https://github.com/sass/node-sass

say

> includePaths
>
> ```
> Type: Array<String>
> Default: []
> ```
>
> An array of paths that LibSass can look in to attempt to resolve your
>   @import declarations. When using data, it is recommended that you use
>   this.

so this whould work ??

```
var path = require('path');

gulp.task('sass', function () {  
    gulp.src('assets/scss/main.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass({
        includePaths: [path.resolve('./assets/sass')]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
    /* Reload the browser CSS after every change */
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});
```

Comment: I do not use node-neat at all. It is embedded somehow within the code wrongly.